# Can't get minutes and seconds out of the __TIME__ variable in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, environment-variables, character

I am trying to extract the minute and second out of the **TIME** variable.
The below code works fine when the `char sec_str[3] = {s1, s2};` line is commented.
but when uncommented, the min_str variable suddenly have the seconds added to it as well.

I am really confused as to why is this happening, and the maximum length min_str array can have is only 2, then how come it is storing 4 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        printf("%s\n",__TIME__);

        char m1 = __TIME__[3];
        char m2 = __TIME__[4];

        char s1 = __TIME__[6];
        char s2 = __TIME__[7];

        printf("%c %c %c %c", m1, m2, s1, s2);

        char min_str[2] = {m1, m2};
        //char sec_str[3] = {s1, s2};

        printf("\nlength of min_str is %ld\n",strlen(min_str));

        printf("\n%s ", min_str);
}
```

This is with sec_str commented:

```
22:30:20
3 0 2 0
length of min_str is 2

30
```

This is with sec_str not commented:

```
22:32:09
3 2 0 9
length of min_str is 4

3209
```

Comment: `__TIME__` is not a variable, it is macro expanding to the time of the *compilation*. Are you sure you want it and not the real time the program runs?

Comment: `strlen` is returning `size_t`, and the correct format specifier is `%zu` and not `%ld`.

Comment: Your `min_str` is not null-terminated.

Comment: Try `char min_str[3] = {m1, m2};` & `char sec_str[3] = {s1, s2};`